# Calculate Euclidean Distances Between One Point in a Bidimensional Coordinate System From All Other Points

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I need to implement a euclidean distance sum algorithm. For that, I will need to calculate distances between the given input data and sum the distances between the combination of all given coordenates.

Consider the following input data:

```
point1(x1,y1),point2(x2,y2),point3(x3,y3),point4(x4,y4)
```

What I am looking to achieve here is, I want to calculate distance of point 1 from ALL other points.

And I have to repeat this for ALL other points

Can someone help me please?

Comment: [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any external library you can use this simple function:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt

def euclidean_dist(p1, p2):
    return sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)

def sum_dist(points):
    return sum(euclidean_dist(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in combinations(points, 2))
```

Example:

```
>>> sum_dist([(1,2), (0,3), (5,-4)])
17.227641380343698
>>> euclidean_dist((1,2), (0,3)) + euclidean_dist((1,2), (5,-4)) + euclidean_dist((0,3), (5,-4))
17.227641380343698
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this would look something like this:

```
   for i in range(0,#number of points):
        for j in range(i+1, #number of points):
            calculate_dist(points[i],points[j])
```

You don't have to calculate the distance from every point to every other point because then you will calculate the distances twice, therefor the inner loop starts at i+1 (+1 because there's no need to calculate distance to itself).